# How to debug Backbone/Marionette

Tags: asp.net, backbone.js, marionette

I am working on a task on asp.net and am idle on one aspx page, where it helps to increase/decrease the calendar cell, I just wanted to know the value of a variable by debugging so that , i will know what to change am new to marionette and need some help to get those values so that i can go ahead with this issue, am attaching the script.

i even searched many sites to debug the backbone, got chrome plugin to debug but of no help.

[image]

Comment: I am updating this because, I found way to debug the Marionette, along with Seebiscuit's , You can install Chrome plugin which is easily found in internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add  `<%debugger%>` at the top of your template. It will break an attached JavaScript debugger (such as Chrome's Dev Tools), when Underscore begins to populate the template.

Comment: Thanks seebiscuit, using above debugger was getting error on aspx, I changed it to {%debugger;%} later i used chrome backbone plugin to debug the code.

Comment: I did not know that you had to use curly braces in aspx. I assume the rendering engine converts them to `< >`. Good to know. Btw, how did you use the Bb plugin to break inside a template?

Comment: got chrome plugin from online, downloaded it, and used {%debugger;%} before the variable and reloaded the page it automatically stops at debugger and just hovering on variable will give us value. I still have one question about Marionette using css height in cell of a calendar let me know if you are interested, I will post and send you the link

Comment: I'll be happy to answer your question. Make a new post and reply in this thread. BTW, even without the plugin, your debugger will break on `{% debugger %}`.

Comment: If you feel this answer was the correct solution to your problem, please mark it as the accepted Answer.

Comment: I have acceted the answer as yours and posted my another question here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578113/passing-value-from-marionette-to-aspx"