# Passing value from Marionette to aspx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, marionette

I am new to Marionette but progressing day by day, I am in a situation where i have calculated value on Marionette.js file and i need to pass that value back to aspx, value is css height value, am attaching my code pic and let me know what i am doing wrong, even passing hardcoded value from .js file it is not getting that value in UI.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused. You want to pass a value calculated in a front end template to an aspx template that gets revered on the back end? This is not a Marionette issue, it's a RESTful question. You need to set up a RESTful infrastructure on your backend to feed values to your aspx template.

Comment: most probably you are right, anyways i could able to find the way , to get values back to aspx. thanks for your help seebiscuit.